# R CMD build . fails: "argument is of length zero"

Tags: r, r-package

`R CMD build .` on my package failed with the following unhelpful output:

```
* checking for file ‘./DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘myPackage’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
Error in if (dep$op != ">=") next : argument is of length zero
Execution halted
```

RStudio also gives unhelpful output:

> ERROR: The build directory does not contain a DESCRIPTION
>   file so cannot be built as a package.
>
> Build directory: ~/myPackage

(the `DESCRIPTION` file clearly exists)

Here is my `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Package: myPackage
Version: 0.1.0
Title: This is my package
Author: Michael Chirico
Maintainer: Michael Chirico <my_email@gmail.com>
Depends: R
Description: My package is great!
Imports: Rcpp (>= 1.0.0)
LinkingTo: Rcpp
```

What is wrong with my package structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update 2020-04-27

As of the current `svn` revision (78311), this question is obsolete -- the internal function `tools:::.split_description` now simply drops the R dependency if `>=` is not given.

This was a result of this bug report:

https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17768

---

#### relevant to R versions 4.0.0 and earlier

`Depends: R` *must* have an R version dependency:

```
Depends: R (>= 3.0.0)
```

(or whatever is appropriate)

This is stated in [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies):

> It makes no sense to declare a dependence on R without a version specification, nor on the package `base`: this is an R package and package `base` is always available.

So, I could also just remove this line (if my package has no other dependencies).

With this, the build completes right away.

While this is clear in retrospect, perhaps the path to figuring out what was going wrong can also be illustrative (since this particular error message didn't give me any search results):

> Error in if (dep$op != ">=") next : argument is of length zero

Certainly looks familiar as R code -- clearly `dep$op` (whatever that is) is missing/not declared for some reason. What's not clear is what code's being executed/what function is producing this error.

But, whatever code it is must be inside [the R source](https://github.com/wch/r-source), so we can:

1. Try our luck with GitHub's in-repository search for the message (might be tough to match due to the various delimiters/other characters usually dropped from a web search)
2. Clone the repo and use `grep` (etc) in the source code (more flexible, but requires downloading the full R source if you don't already have it)

Today, I was lucky enough to get a [hit on GitHub for `"if (dep$op != ">=") next"`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?q=%22if+%28dep%24op+%21%3D+%22%3E%3D%22%29+next%22&unscoped_q=%22if+%28dep%24op+%21%3D+%22%3E%3D%22%29+next%22) in two files; `src/library/tools/R/build.R` looks like it's on the nose.

Here is the region where that snippet is found:

```
ixup_R_dep <- function(pkgname, ver = "2.10")
    {
        desc <- .read_description(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"))
        Rdeps <- .split_description(desc)$Rdepends2
        for(dep in Rdeps) {
            if(dep$op != '>=') next
            if(dep$version >= package_version(ver)) return()
        }
```

This is in the `tools` package so the helper functions are available as e.g. `tools:::.read_description`.

With this, it was easy to see that `Rdeps` was capturing the `Depends: R` section of `DESCRIPTION` and that it was expecting to find a version tag as well; `dep$op` is the `op`erator being applied to the `dep`endency.